# Hide label while editing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, vector, editing

When I edit a feature in QGIS and it has a label, it shows up and is often in the way so that I can't choose to place the vertex there (under the label - see example in picture - white label *ÅTVIDABERG*).

Can I choose not to automatically show that label?

[image: picture when label shows up]

Comment: Can you provide your label settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be the "Map Tip Tool" - just disable it, then you will get rid of it:

[image: with enabled map tip]

and with disabled:

[image]